# why can't I tap uibutton in simulator but I can on my hardware iPhone?

Tags: ios, uikit, ios-simulator

I have two buttons on the top of my view controller, which is modally presented. The strange thing is that the buttons are not at all selectable when I click on them in the simulator.
The buttons cause no issues when I use them on my iPhone.

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

That's the way I add my function to the button

Whole button code:

```
let post: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton()

        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 30)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray.adjust(by: 20), for: .normal)
        btn.isEnabled = false
        btn.setTitle("Post", for: .normal)
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .bold)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        return btn
    }()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what I had to do was change the iPhone to an X from an 8 in the simulator to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

- view controller overrides touchesBegan(_:with:) method which don't call the super.
- UIView userInteractionEnabled is set to false on that button via InterfaceBuilder or programmatically
- button is below a view which has userInteractionEnabled set to false

Comment: how would I not override touchesBegan(_:with:)? Since I can't see that in the code. I  also don't have userInteractionEnabled set to false anywhere

Comment: @Peter is was a suggestion that it could be a cause of a problem